# how to add or subtract a value from a column in oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update

i am trying to create an update oracle procedure that updates a column after a change has been made.

```
Mass  |  SLAB   |  Mass Decreased/Increase
1100  | 200     |   100  // mass increased by 100
1000  | 200     | -100  // mass decrased by 100
```

i have the above table when any changes are made to the mass column the difference between the original mass and the mass that it has been changed to gets stored into Mass Decreased/Increase column with it been a positive or negative value. i need to minus or add the value from my Mass Decreased/Increase to the Slab column. Im not sure how to detect if the mass has decreased or increased. Can u use an If statement ?

for example if its incresed

```
slab = 200 + 100
```

if decreased

```
slab =200-100
```

this is what i have

```
    procedure update_table(massNew number) 

 is

 begin 

        update
             Table t1
        set
             t1.Mass =massNew,

             t1.Mass Decreased/Increase= massNew - t1.Mass,
             t1.slab=t1.slab - (massNew - t1.Mass) // i added it to minus from the slab if there is a decrease but how to i set it to automatically detect if its a positive/negative number

        where code in ( select ct.description
        from codeTable  ct
        where ct.code=code
        );             
        commit;
```

Comment: Did you already try a Before Update trigger? There you can reference the new and old vaslues...

Comment: @Tyron78: don't put business logic in a trigger. It never turns out well.

Comment: OK, then another possibility would be to read within the procedure the old values into variables and do the comparison / calculation basing on these variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following update seems to do what you want though I have no idea about the criteria for which record in the table to actually apply the update to.

```
UPDATE table t1
SET    t1.mass   = in_mass,
   t1.slab      =
      CASE
         WHEN (t1.mass < in_mass) THEN t1.slab + (in_mass - t1.mass)
         WHEN (t1.mass > in_mass) THEN t1.slab - (t1.mass - in_mass)
         ELSE t1.slab
      END,
   t1.description      =
      CASE
         WHEN (t1.mass < in_mass) THEN in_mass - t1.mass || ' mass increase by ' || ABS (in_mass - t1.mass)
         WHEN (t1.mass > in_mass) THEN in_mass - t1.mass || ' mass decrease by ' || ABS (in_mass - t1.mass)
         ELSE 'No change'
      END;
```

EDIT: Test procedure included.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mass_test_proc (in_mass IN NUMBER)
IS
BEGIN
UPDATE mass_test_table t1
SET    t1.mass   = in_mass,
       t1.slab   =
            CASE
              WHEN (t1.mass < in_mass) THEN t1.slab + (in_mass - t1.mass)
              WHEN (t1.mass > in_mass) THEN t1.slab - (t1.mass - in_mass)
              ELSE t1.slab
            END,
       t1.description      =
            CASE
              WHEN (t1.mass < in_mass) THEN in_mass - t1.mass || ' mass increase by ' || ABS (in_mass - t1.mass)
              WHEN (t1.mass > in_mass) THEN in_mass - t1.mass || ' mass decrease by ' || ABS (in_mass - t1.mass)
              ELSE 'No change'
            END;

COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error - '||sqlcode);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('MSG - '||substr(sqlerrm,1,64));
END;
```

Comment: i tried this now,its adding the difference to the slab even tho its a decrease .However your logic makes sense ,im not sure what could be wrong now, cause the t1.mass is greater then the in_mass inorder for it to minus

Comment: Not sure what you have done there then. I've just done a quick test with that update in a procedure and all 3 columns get updated as expected. I've made an edit and pasted my test procedure code.

Comment: its correct,thanks, i didnt realise i had it as (in_mass - t1.mass) for the negative figure when it should have been (t1.mass - in_mass) cause the negatives where cancelling each other out.

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the
Case Expression

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

e.g.:

```
UPDATE tabx   
SET colx=   CASE  
                        WHEN (x = y)  THEN x   
                        WHEN (x = z)  THEN y
                        ELSE z 
                        END
```

Comment: This doesn't help to evaluate, which valus is old / before the update and which is new... you still have to evaluate these beforehand.